# PHP shell_exec() unable to run part of shell script

Tags: php, bash, git, webhooks, shell-exec

I have encountered a strange problem. I have created a gitlab custom webhook. The webhook service is written in php (gitlab.php). The php script, when called with proper payload, should start an automated deployment. The deployment script is basically a shell script (deploy.sh)

**Code of gitlab.php**

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
// Converts it into a PHP object
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$secret = "";
foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) { 
    if($name=='X-Gitlab-Token') {
        $secret = $value;
    }
}

if($secret=="mysecretcode" && $data['object_kind']=="push") {
    file_put_contents("/opt/lampp/htdocs/autodeploy/autodeploy.log", "Webhook auto deployment started at ". date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "\n". shell_exec("sh /opt/lampp/htdocs/autodeploy/deploy.sh")."\n**********************************************\n\n", FILE_APPEND);
    die("Deployment success");
}
else {
 die("Auth token invalid or no triggerable event found");
}
?>
```

**Code of deploy.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "/opt/lampp/htdocs/nodejs/myapp"
echo "Stopping application..."
forever stop index.js
cd ..
sudo rm -rf myapp
echo "Pulling latest code from gitlab..."
git clone -b "master" https://myusername%40domain.com:MyEncodedPass123@gitlab.com/myusername/myapp.git
cd myapp
echo "Installing dependencies..."
npm install
echo "Starting application..."
forever start index.js
echo "Application started on port 3000."
```

When I push code to gitlab, it triggers the webhook and initiates the deployment process and I see my webhook file gitlab.php returned success response to Gitlab and has written following output in autodeploy.log file

```
Webhook auto deployment started at 2021-10-03 13:32:07
Stopping application...
Pulling latest code from gitlab...
Installing dependencies...
Starting application...
Application started on port 3000.

**********************************************
```

But, the deployment actually never happens. It just runs the `echo` statements (and may be `cd`, `rm` etc as well) and rest of the shell commands are kind of ignored or not executed. It for sure doesn't run the `git clone` command, because I do not see latest code getting refreshed on my server from gitlab. Not sure though what happens to the `npm` and `forever` commands.

By the way, this is a Ubuntu VPS server with latest ApacheFriends XAMPP server installed, php v8. All the three files mentioned above reside at the same path i.e. `/opt/lampp/htdocs/autodeploy` and my deploy.sh script tries to deploy a separate nodejs application in `/opt/lampp/htdocs/nodejs/myapp` folder. Strangely enough, when I run deploy.sh directly from terminal it deploys the latest code successfully. Which means, all the statements in the script gets executed as expected. It only fails when executed from the php script using shell_exec() function.

Any clue what could be the reason?

Comment: Before anyone says "never use shell exec" note how while its still not a great idea, there is no input by the user, so no shell RCE is possible

Comment: `set -e` at the beginning to catch all errors. Execute the script manually under the same user as the webhook.

Comment: `sh` is not the same as `bash`, you're mixing the two. Also, if you have a program with a shebang line, you don't redundantly specify the interpreter on the commandline but set the executable flag. Fix those things first. Also, read the GitLab docs carefully: In some cases, it uses a POSIX-compatible shell (`sh`) and not `bash`.

Comment: the [documentation for shell_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) doesn't state it clearly, but chances are you only get the `stdout` of your command, not `stderr` (the first comment certainly seems to indicate that, it would also match "it's the same thing as backtick"). Try running `shell_exec("sh .../deploy.sh 2>&1")`. I also second phd's suggestion : turn `set -e` on, at least your script will halt when you get an error.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for `shell_exec`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) doesn't state it clearly, but chances are you only get the `stdout` of your command, not its `stderr` -- the [first comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php#106250) certainly seems to indicate that, it would also match the "it's the same thing as backtick" decription.
If such is the case, you simply don't have the error messages in your output.

Try running :

```
shell_exec("sh .../deploy.sh 2>&1")
```

I also second @phd's suggestion (in the comments to your question) : turn `set -e` on, at least your script will halt when you get an error.
Chances are your current script would fail at the first line : `cd "/opt/lampp/htdocs/nodejs/myapp"`.

I also strongly advise to drop the `sudo` in `sudo rm -rf ...`.